# disable sort checked choose by alphabet or number in antd checkbox group

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this code
`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { Checkbox } from 'antd';
const CheckboxGroup = Checkbox.Group;
const plainOptions = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'];

const App = () => {
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (list) => {
    setCheckedList(list);
    console.log(list);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CheckboxGroup
        options={plainOptions}
        value={checkedList}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have problem with that when I click by this sort : first :Orange, second: Apple the console.log(list) be ["Apple", "Orange"]
I need to the output be ["Orange", "Apple"] It should be in the order I chose, not sorted

I try to fix this problem but it didn't handle
and the sort of my checked is important to me for another code

Answer (score 0):

To implement this you need more complex logic of `onChange` function. You need to go through all elements in `checkedList` and remove all unchecked. Then add all checked elements from the `list`, that are absent in `checkedList`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Checkbox } from "antd";
const CheckboxGroup = Checkbox.Group;
const plainOptions = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"];

const App = () => {
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (list) => {
    let nextCheckedList = checkedList.filter((item) => list.includes(item));
    const newChecked = list.find((item) => !nextCheckedList.includes(item));
    if (newChecked != undefined) {
      nextCheckedList.push(newChecked);
    }

    setCheckedList(nextCheckedList);
    console.log(nextCheckedList);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CheckboxGroup
        options={plainOptions}
        value={checkedList}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```